# Updating bulk record in mysql taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to update a large table with more than 100k rows. I am  fetching data from the table applying preg_match and then updating the table again with new values.

The problem is that it take hours to update all the record in the database.

Code that I'm using

```
$sql = "SELECT id, city_hotel, state, cc1 FROM hotel_names";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$array = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $array[] = $row; 
  }
}
foreach ($array as $arr)
{       
    if (preg_match_all('/\(([A-Za-z0-9 ]+?)\)/', $arr['city_hotel'], $out))
        {
            if(!empty($out))
            {
                $STATE[] = $out[1];
                //print_r($STATE);
                foreach ($STATE as $state)
                {
                    $st = $state[0];
                    print_r($state) ;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE hotel_names SET state = ? WHERE id = ? ");
                    $stmt->bind_param('ss' ,$st, $arr['id']);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    echo "State Updated <br>";
                                if(preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$arr['city_hotel']))
                                {
                                    $city = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$arr['city_hotel']);
                                    //echo $city = trim($city).'<br>';
                                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE hotel_names SET  city_hotel = ? WHERE id = ? ");
                                    $stmt->bind_param('ss' , $city, $arr['id']);
                                    $stmt->execute();       
                                    echo "City Updated <br>";   
                                }
                }
            }
        }   
}
```

Comment: can you show your table schema with 2-3 dummy records?

Comment: One of the advantages of using prepared statements is that you prepare them once and use multiple times.  So prepare the two updates at the start (using different variables to hold each one) and then bind and execute for each update.

Comment: See my articles on [_high speed ingestion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) and [_big deletes (or updates)_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Answer (score 0):

It is taking time because you are executing sql again and again in loop.so it is generating so many processes.you can execute multiple queries in on execution process follow the given link.

[(PDO PHP) The fastest way to update or insert multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959784/pdo-php-the-fastest-way-to-update-or-insert-multiple-rows)